# What's going on with my UIButtons in a xib?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a set of UIButtons (defined in a xib) who have labels that need to be updated periodically. In the ViewDidLoad method of the view controller of those buttons' superview, I have an update method that does, for each button:

```
button.titleLabel.text = @"Relevant Text";
[button setNeedsDisplay];
```

and when you tap a button, another method runs which pops up a UIAlertView, which in turn calls back a method on the view controller which does much the same thing as the initial text setting method:

```
button.titleLabel.text = @"New Text";
[button setNeedsDisplay];
```

however, this code simply isn't working, the button label's text doesn't get updated in either method, it remains a blank white button. In the xib I don't define any text on the buttons - there's no point, the button text doesn't make sense unless it's set at runtime. Anyway, on a lark, I decided to set the text of one of the buttons to "test test test".

Now, when I tap that particular button, it pops up the UIAlertView but in the background changes the text of the button to "test test test test". And *this* time, the UIAlertView callback does what I expect it to and sets the text for only that button. When I hit it again, the text goes *back* to "test test test test" until I dismiss the UIAlertView, which again will run the callback method and set the button text to whatever the method should.

I have no idea what's going on here, or why setting the text initially in the xib has any relation to whether or not I can set that text later programatically. Obviously this isn't the behavior I want, I want to know how to for sure set the text on the buttons.

Edit:  SVD's advice about setTitle:ForState: solved my problem, thanks. I'm still curious though as to why the title label set in the .xib shows up, but only when I have a UIAlertView pop up.

Comment: Do you have an outlet for your button that's actually connected? Are you sure it's not nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use [setTitle: forState:] to set the button title for normal and highlighted (or selected) state.

(And do make sure the button is connected to the outlet, as jtbandes points out).

Comment: I had the exact same problem and using the [setTitle: forState] method set things right.