# What's going on with my UIButtons in a xib?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's going on with my UIButtons in a xib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072146/whats-going-on-with-my-uibuttons-in-a-xib)

I have some UIButtons defined in a xib, code to initialize their labels to some text, and when you press the button a UIALertView pops up and when dismissed runs a callback method that also changes the text of the label. THe label changing code looks like:

```
button.titleLabel.text = @"Whatever text";
[button setNeedsDisplay];
```

However, none of these methods are working. In the xib none of the buttons have a label initially set, so on a lark I decided to set one of them to "test test test test". Now, for that button alone, when I hit the button and the UIAlertView pops up, in the background it changes to "test test test test", until I dismiss the AlertView. Then, the button lable text gets set to some value, which is the behavior I want. When I hit the button again, the text *again* goes back to "test test test test" behind the ALertView, until I dismiss it again and it gets reset. What's going on here, and how do I get the text to always update when I set button.titleLabel.text to something?